# Blender solid color with displaying edges?

Tags: 3d-view, edges, wireframe

I am coming from 3ds Max.

Why I can't get a simple way to switch from solid to solid with edges ( without changing the color of the faces to a color that matches the background?

What am I missing? How to I simply change to a view that just adds edges to the solid display?

EDITED:

Ok  the  solution I found was not solution at all ..I was so angry that tricked  myself to believe for a while  it is a solution>IT is not!

Once you add the overlayed wireframe..you can'T switch by any shortcut to the same solid without edges visible??

So problem is still there is so BASIC THING I CAN"T believe Blender exists the way it is:
1.Every Architect or modeler most basic move while he models is to toggle between mode solid with edges and solid without edges and that is not possible in Blender!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of 3DS max with the type of view you would like to see?

Comment: If you want to display the wireframe there's a Wireframe option in the Viewport Overlays panel

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9wH6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9wH6.jpg)
Please see simple example how it is in 3ds max and what it is in Blender..

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jryoV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jryoV.jpg) and that is the Blender display

Comment: you can see it that way only in edit mode i object mode you it i the same color as the background ...no idea why is that doesn't make any sense to me[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh3j1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh3j1.jpg)

Comment: AND FINALLY found it..it is turned off by default in Solid mode..( from Viewport DISplay options as an overlay ) ...so it is easily confused with the toggle state of wireframe mode............
pfff..I see some nice things in Blender..but it's a pitty the UX for simple basic things is so terrible ..

Comment: Ok. So that's Wireframe on the Viewport Overlays menu. If you want that to be the default every time you start Blender (which most Blender users don't...), start Blender with a new scene, check that setting on the Overlay menu, and then use the File > Defaults > Save Startup File menu.

Comment: Please do not use the answer section for comments or additional information. You can edit your original question by clicking on "Edit" underneath your question. Stack Exchange is a Q&A website, not a regular forum.

Comment: @japanase, yes, my second message: " there's a Wireframe option in the Viewport Overlays panel"

Comment: moonboots..I have attached one

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 3DS Max, but maybe switch on <kbd>Cavity</kbd> on the <kbd>Viewport Shading</kbd> menu?

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion but no!..I am looking for something a lot simple and basic...

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing in 3DS Max is the **Edged Faces display**, which you can toggle with the <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut:

[image: 3ds edged faces]

It isn't rendering the viewport models as wireframe, it is displaying the visible edges on top of the viewport's render.

In Blender, any kind of information you want to display on top of the viewport's rendered image is called an Overlay and can be usually managed on a per-viewport basis via the viewport's Overlay popover.

You will find a Wireframe option under the Overlay's popover:

[image: wireframe overlay]

You can assign a shortcut to it by pressing <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the checkbox > Assign to shortcut.

This is not to be confused with the viewport shading Wireframe, which is similar to 3DS Max's Wireframe mode (shortcut <kbd>F3</kbd>):

[image: wireframe shading]

In 3DS Max's wireframe Mode:

[image: 3ds wireframe mode]

---

3DS Pictures credit to [3D Max Shortcuts | What are the Autodesk 3D Max Keyboard Shortcuts?](https://www.educba.com/3d-max-shortcuts/)

Comment: hI lOLOCK.Thanks for the answer .Idid that and it works but that is when you are not in edit mode..Normally you need to be in edit mode when you use that ..and in edit mode I don't see that as possibilty.. IF you have to toggle between object > edit mode that might work but still has it's flows as if you have hidden geometry in edit mode it will pop out in object mode....etc

Comment: No, wires should always be drawn on top when in edit mode on a mesh object. Make sure you are in edit mode in that specific object and that it is a mesh object.